# How to use Automapper with included linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

How to configure Automapper profile to have the same result with manual mapper.

I map Dto manually as follows

```
public static IQueryable<EmployeeDto> ConvertToDto(this IQueryable<Employee> employees)
{
    return (from employee in employees
            select new EmployeeDto()
            {
                BusinessEntityId = employee.Person.BusinessEntityId,
                FirstName = employee.Person.FirstName,
                LastName = employee.Person.LastName,
                BirthDate = employee.Person.BirthDate,
                PersonDto = new PersonDto()
                {
                    BusinessEntityId = employee.Person.BusinessEntityId,
                    FirstName = employee.Person.FirstName,
                    LastName = employee.Person.LastName,
                    BirthDate = employee.Person.BirthDate,

                },
            });
}
```

My request:

```
IQueryable<EmployeeDto> employees = context.Employees.ConvertToDto().AsQueryable();
```

SQL

```
SELECT [p].[BusinessEntityId], [p].[FirstName], [p].[LastName], [p].[BirthDate]
FROM [PersonCollection].[Employees] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [PersonCollection].[People] AS [p] ON [e].[BusinessEntityId] = [p].[BusinessEntityId]
ORDER BY [p].[BusinessEntityId]
OFFSET @__TypedProperty_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__TypedProperty_1 ROWS ONLY
```

**update**

classTdo :

```
public class EmployeeDto : PersonDtoBase
{
    public EmployeeDto()
    {
    }    
    public PersonDto Person { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PersonDtoBase
{ 
    public int BusinessEntityId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }    
}
```

source :

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key] public int BusinessEntityId { get; set; }
    public Guid RowguidEmployee { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")] 
    public DateTime ModifiedDateEmplyee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BusinessEntityId))][InverseProperty(nameof(PersonCollection.Person.Employee))] 
    public Person Person { get; set; }    
}
```

**Here Workaround.:**

```
public class DtoProfile : Profile
{
    public DtoProfile()
    {
        CreateProjection<Person, PersonDto>();
        CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>( MemberList.Destination)
                .ForMember(e => e.BusinessEntityId, o => o.MapFrom(o => o.Person.BusinessEntityId))
                .ForMember(e => e.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(o => o.Person.FirstName))
                .ForMember(e => e.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(o => o.Person.LastName))
                .ForMember(e => e.BirthDate, o => o.MapFrom(o => o.Person.BirthDate))   
    }        
}
```

Query:

```
IQueryable<EmployeeDto> employees = context.Employees.ProjectTo<EmployeeDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).AsQueryable();
```

result SQL

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS bit), [p].[BusinessEntityId], [p].[FirstName], [p].[LastName], [p].[BirthDate]
FROM [PersonCollection].[Employees] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [PersonCollection].[People] AS [p] ON [e].[BusinessEntityId] = [p].[BusinessEntityId]
ORDER BY [p].[BusinessEntityId]
OFFSET @__TypedProperty_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__TypedProperty_1 ROWS ONLY
```

In the query there is a CAST(0 AS bit).

**Question**
is there any better less to configure the Profile in this kind of scenario

Comment: I am not sure what your question or problem is. Is it that you don't know how to configure AutoMapper to do what you want? If so, what have you tried, and what does it do that isn't what you want?

Comment: Does the code that you have compile? Run? Work as you wish? If so, what more do you want it to do, that it can't do?

Comment: It might also help to add the definition of the class `Employee`.

Comment: I want to do the same thing but with automapper, but I don't know how to do it, I tried with this configuration
  CreateProjection<Person, PersonDto>();
 CreateProjection<Employee, EmployeeDto>().ForMember(c => c.PersonDto, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
Query does not join

Comment: That's pretty much what I want (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/94982214d347990340ca6d3d70f716acf0037ca6/src/IntegrationTests/ExplicitExpansion/ExpandCollections.cs)

Comment: From what I can make out of the query The join doesn't appear to be required since the PersonDTO is populated with the data from the same record?  Does EF/Automapper not populate the PersonDto?

Comment: I changed the clean name PersonDto to Person in the EmployeeDto class, now it does the join but they populate the fields, I will update for further testing.